# How do I ignore/unregister more than 1 plugin for a module

Tags: python, pytest

I have created a pytest module, which is under a project root. Now there are multiple plugins installed as a part of the root project, but I am seeing issues in my module because of that. So I want to unregister the plugins that I dont need, and are installed at the root level.

I did check this doc:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/plugins.html#deactivating-unregistering-a-plugin-by-name
and tried:

[pytest]
addopts = -p no:NAME

in my pytest.ini file.
It works if I give a single plugin. But I was wondering how to do this if I want multiple plugins to be unregistered?

I tried a bunch of options, but none of them worked

Comment: `pytest -p no:plugin1 -p no:plugin2` etc.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much @hoefling! that worked...